# Markov Chains. How to find F with different shape of I and Q

Tags: markov-chains

First for all I want to say that I deal with Markov Chains only second day so I have some problems with terminology. Sorry for that.

I need to solve following matrix:

[image]

Now in I need to compute `FR`. In order to compute `FR` I need to find `F` first which is `(I-Q)^-1`.

So my question is what if `I` and `Q` have different shape. On the image above `Q` is smaller than `I`. And what about case when `Q` is larger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$"I"$  that you see in $(I-Q)^{-1}$is an identity matrix and is of the same dimension as that of Q.   The $"I"$ that you see in the image is also an identity matrix by construction and lets you know the number of absorbing states that you have in the system .  This one and Q need not have the same dimension.